# Wijmo Flexgrid how to get number of rows pasted/Get index of row where data is pasted

Tags: wijmo

I want to change data while pasting. I am pasting a number of rows and I want to change on pasted data.
I am trying on pasting event but I am not able to get the index of pasted rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the event data that was sent to the pasting event:

```
grid.pasting.addHandler(function(s, e) {
  let row = e.row; // gets the starting row index
  let rng = e.range; // gets the whole cell range which were affected
});
```